# What are best safety practices for visits to waste water treatment plants (WWTP)?

Tags: safety, waste-water-treatment

In my position I'll frequently visit wastewater treatment plants, often when refurbishments work happen. What are best practices I should adopt to avoid accidents?

Comment: Isn't this too broad? Also would the answers be just as applicable to any industrial or construction site? If you want specific answers, then you will have to give a location. A lot of these issues are handled by government agencies.

Comment: With wwtp you have (possible) infection issues that don't arise in many industrial sites, I hope. I'm not asking about regulations but the actual things I should do/not do. I don't understand the broadness?

Comment: @mart - this is overly broad.  There are multi-hour long courses that cover plant safety due to the number of potential hazards that could be present.  It's a good question, but it's too big of a question to fit into the StackExchange Q&A format.  A proper answer would be the equivalent of a small book.

Comment: I'm not talking about directly supervising work or operating the plant (I wouldn't touch either without way more training).

Comment: Even simply _visiting_ a plant carries a number or risks and hazards.  I know of several engineering firms that require multi-hour training before they'll allow employees to set foot on the site.  If refurbishment construction is going on, the number of hazards increases.  Don't get me wrong, it's a good and interesting question.  But it's too big of a question for the site's format.

Comment: CAn you point me at such a seminar? I'm  sure it will be in the wrong country (I'm in Germany) but would be interesting nonetheless. My employer is obviously another breed of engineering firm.

Comment: The courses I'm aware of are proprietary / internal use only, sorry.

Comment: Also, as the question is worded, it is a "top ten" list that can never be completed.

Comment: meta: http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/353/is-my-question-on-safety-practices-for-wwtp-plant-visits-salvageble

Answer (score 1):

Some practices include:

- Announce visit to staff and inquire about potential hazards
- watch out for traffic
- watch out for machines that start on their own
- don't run, becareful around ladders etc, watch were to step,
- don't hang around under cranes,
- don't smoke in zones with explosion hazard or bring ignition sources
- don't touch sewage
- wash hands after visit
- only enter cellars or shafts when they are activly ventilated and/or after gas measurements have determined them to be safe

Comment: This answer is not finished because I don't know what I don't know ...

Comment: Your question was not specific enough to have an engineering answer.  You can ask and answer the world in a single question - not on SE, at least.  Maybe you want to write a book instead?